# Lodash returns "true" instead of the actual number when using index accessor

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, lodash, unix-timestamp

I'm using a Lodash chain function like so

```
let currentUser = _.chain(allUsers)
.find(o => o[0] == 'username')
.value();
```

that ends up returning a result like below

```
[
'username',
'93.184.216.34',
1658480701,
1658483502
]
//user name, user IP address, user registration Unix time, user last login Unix time
```

which is totally fine, but when I'm trying to access the user's last login time using index accessor like

```
console.log(currentUser[3]);
```

for some users, it returns the correct data (For example, `1658483502`) and for some other users, it returns the value `true` instead, which is really unexpected.
It's worth mentioning using the Lodash built-in function `_.nth(3)` instead of the index accessor is not working either.

Comment: maybe the `currentUser[3]` is true in that filtered. maybe you can do a log on currentUser. worth to note that if the find result is undefined the currentUser[3] will throw error so _nth is an option or do proper checks

Comment: the `currentUser[3]` actually has timestamp data in it but somehow it returns `true` instead. The array has been validated before accessing its 3rd index. @cmgchess

Comment: this is hard to reproduce based on the data you have already provided. can you have a look at waht currentUser is before accessing 3

Comment: are you sure your data isn't at fault?

Comment: The code works perfectly fine for other indexes such as `currentUser[0]` or `currentUser[1]` but it only acts weird for the last index, and the data is valid as far as I checked using `console.log(currentUser)` before `console.log(currentUser[3])`

Comment: is there some middle layer that changes the data

Comment: If `currentuser` really is that array depicted above, than `currentuser[3]` cannot be `true` I suspect there is a problem with your data, or you are doing something in between you are not showing us ...